# When I hit enter during input focus, the page refreshes

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is, that when I hit enter while the input is in focus, the page refreshes.

code:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const todo_input = document.querySelector('.todoInput');

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key)
    if(todo_input.innerHTML != '' && todo_input == document.activeElement && e.key == "Enter") {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('submit')
        const todoEl = document.createElement('li');
        todoEl.classList.add('todo');
        todoEl.innerHTML = todo_input.innerHTML;
        todoEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
            todoEl.classList.add('done');
        })
        todoEl.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            todoEl.remove();
        })
    }
})
```

```html
<form class="wrapper">
    <input placeholder="Enter your todo" class="todoInput">
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
</form>
```

I would be very happy if somebody would answer.

Comment: because enter triggers form submit.

Comment: use `e.prventDefault()`

Comment: I tried it but the page refreshes before I can prevent the event

Comment: How can I fix it Yogi

Comment: You only call preventDefault when todo_input.innerHTML != '' … which is never.

Comment: todo_input.innerHTML != '' isn't never, because when you hit enter and the input ins't in focus and there is nothing typed in, then todo_input.innerHTML != '' is true

Comment: I think the problem is in html, because after I pasted the html code for the "run snippet code" I tried it without javascript code and it waas the same

Comment: Well (a) You don’t want it to submit the form if something *is* typed in there **and** you also doesn’t want to submit the form if something is *not* typed in there but (b) todo_input.innerHTML will never be true because inputs can’t have children.

Comment: BTW, You should use `todo_input.value` to get the input values, not using `todo_input.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

The `refreshing` behavior appears because `ENTER` on the input was cheated as a *submit* event on form. To prevent this, you could either `preventDefault` when you press `ENTER` or change the `<form>` to `<div>`.

BTW, there are more bugs in your app:

- You should access input value using `todo_input.value` instead of `todo_input.innerHTML`.
- You forget to append the newly created item into `wrapper`.

Try this:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
const todo_input = document.querySelector('.todoInput');

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    console.log(e.key)
    if (e.key == "Enter") {
      e.preventDefault();
      if(todo_input.value != '' && todo_input == document.activeElement) {
        console.log('submit')
        const todoEl = document.createElement('li');
        todoEl.classList.add('todo');
        todoEl.innerHTML = todo_input.value;
        todoEl.addEventListener('click', () => {
            todoEl.classList.add('done');
        })
        todoEl.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            todoEl.remove();
        })
      wrapper.appendChild(todoEl);
    }
    }
    
})
```

```html
<form class="wrapper">
    <input placeholder="Enter your todo" class="todoInput">
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
    <li class="todo">todo1</li>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, it works but can you explain it to me, because I'm a person who wants to understand everything

Comment: @JojosbizzareJS Yes see my new edits on this answer :)

Comment: with "You should access input value using todo_input.value instead of todo_input.innerHTML." you are right, but with the second bug is only for a test, I didn't forget that, but thanks, your answer was very high-quality

Comment: If this answer is helpful and right to the question,  I would be appreciated that you mark this as accepted :)  @JojosbizzareJS

Comment: I voted up, but somebody has voted down so I think you know what happens